# Is there a search algorithm for minimizing number of threads?

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, search, execution-time, xeon-phi

I am using the Intel Xeon Phi coprocessor, which has up to 240 threads, and I am working on minimizing the number of threads used for a particular application (or maximize performance) while being within a percentage of the best execution time. So for example if I have the following measurements:

- Threads | Execution time
- 240       100 s
- 200       105 s
- 150       107 s
- 120       109 s
- 100       120 s

I would like to select a number of threads between 120 and 150, since the "performance curve" there seems to stabilize and the reduction in execution time is not that significant (in this case around 15% of the best measured time. I did this using an exhaustive search algorithm (measuring from 1 to 240 threads), but my problem is that it takes too long for smaller number of threads (obviously depending on the size of the problem).

To try to reduce the number of measurements, I developed a sort of "binary search" algorithm. Basically I have an upper and lower limit (beginning at 0 and 240 threads), I take the value in the middle and measure it and at 240. I get the percent difference between both values and if it is within 15% (this value was selected after analyzing the results for the exhaustive search) I assign a new lower or upper bound. If the difference is larger than 15% then this is a new lower bound (120-240) and if it is smaller then it is a new upper bound (0-120), and if I get a better execution time I store it as the best execution time.

The problem with this algorithm is that first of all this is not necessarily a sorted array of execution times, and for some problem sizes the exhaustive search results show two different minimum, so for example in one I get the best performance at 80 threads and at 170, and I would like to be able to return 80, and not 170 threads as a result of the search. However, for the other cases where there is only one minimum, the algorithm found a value very close to the one expected.

If anyone has a better idea or knows of an existing search algorithm or heuristic that could help me I would be really grateful.

Comment: Why would you want to reduce the number of threads when 240 threads give you maximum performance? Do you have another performance measure? And when you have found an optimal value (whatever optimal means in this case), what are you going to do with it?

Comment: As you know, a binary search will settle at one (of possibly many) local minima. To get the general shape of the curve, measure from 240 threads down to 10 in increments of 10 (that's 24 runs max). Stop when the running time becomes painful, say when the running time is 3 times the best time seen so far.

Comment: @NicoSchertler, using 240 threads doesn't always give maximum performance. The reason for reducing the number of threads is to be able to use the other threads in other computations, or even to reduce energy consumption. This is a first step just to measure the performance and afterwards I will do an analysis of the impact of reducing the number of threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking it that your goal is to get the best relative performance for the least amount of threads, while still maintaining some limit on performance based on a coefficient (<=1) of the best possible performance. IE: If the coefficient is 0.85 then the performance should be no less than 85% of the performance using all threads.

It seems like what you should be trying to do is simply find the minimium number of threads required to obtain the performance bound. Rather than looking at 1-240 threads, start at 240 threads and reduce the number of threads until you can place a lower bound on the performance limit. You can then work up from the lower bound in such a way that you can find the min without passing over it. If you don't have predefined performance bound, then you can calculate one on the fly based on diminishing returns.

1. As long as the performance limit has not been exceeded, half the number of threads (start with max number of threads). The number that exceeds the performance limit is a lower bound on the number of threads required.
2. Starting at the lower bound on the number of threads, Z, add m threads if can be added without getting within the performance limit. Repeatedly double the number of threads added until within the performance limit. If adding the threads get within the performance limit, subtract the last addition and reset the number of threads to be added to m. If even just adding m gets within the limit, then add the last m threads and return the number of threads.

It might be clearer to give an example of what the process looks like step by step. Where Passed means that the number of threads are outside of the performance limits, and failed means they are either on the performance limit or inside of it.

```
Try adding 1m (Z + 1m). Passed. Threads = Z + m.
Try adding 2m (Z + 3m). Passed. Threads = Z + 3m.
Try adding 4m (Z + 7m). Failed. Threads = Z + 3m. Reset.
Try adding 1m. Passed. Threads = Z + 4m.
Try adding 2m. Passed. Threads = Z + 6m.
Z + 7m failed earlier so reset. 
  Comparisons/lookups are cheap, use them to prevent duplication of work.
Try adding 1m. Failed. Threads = Z + 6m. Reset.
Cannot add less than 1m and still in outside of performance limit.
The solution is Z + 7m threads. 
  Since Z + 6m is m threads short of the performance limit.
```

It's a bit inefficient, but it does find the minimium number of threads (>= Z) required to obtain the performance bound to within an error of m-1 threads and requiring only O(log (N-Z)) tests. This should be enough in most cases, but if it isn't just skip step 1 and use Z=m. Unless increasing the number of threads rapidly decreases the run-time causing very slow run times when Z is very small. In which case, doing step 1 and using [interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) can get an idea of how quickly the run-time increases as the number of threads decrease, which is also useful for determining a good performance limit if none is given.